# Submit form(s) in one or multiple requests

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jquery

It's very early in the process so i don't have any actual code to post. I think it's better to get advice on this before developing so you wouldn't have to re-write everything if it doesn't work as expected.
I have this:

[image: multiple form fields]

It's a check-out process. With a lot of custom fields and optional tabs with more fields. Each number has it's own container(or page) with 4 tabs as shown above.

What's more convenient:

a) Create a page for each "number" and submit data on the go.

b) Wrap it up as a single form and submit it altogether.

**"a"** is default. It's what my employers are actually going for (four different `forms`).

If I were to use **"b"** my idea is to create ONE form and depending on the "step" they are at load the fields via `ajax`, wrap it all up and POST it on submit.
Is this good practice? Would the user be able to go back to any "step "in the check-out process at any given time and change the `fields` value?
Maybe I'm way off and you can't do this but I need flexibility given that option **"a"** wouldn't allow users to go back a "step" without re-submitting.

ALL answer will be greatly appreciated.
If you come up with option **"c"**, that's even better.

Comment: Is that a multiple page form, or the tabs are all on the same page (without ajax involved)?

Comment: "It depends". The tabs (or "AJAX") are just pretty decorations, but it *may* be very valid to *not* let a process restart or navigate backwards arbitrarily and always require forward-progress...

Comment: each "number" has it's own tabs. There are 4 "pages" in total. Tabs would be controlled with javascript. I was thinking of making just ONE page and load the "numbers" via AJAX. Each "number" moves as a whole.

Comment: @pst good point. However, this is meant to be a very user friendly form and the "already submitted page link" would still be visible (the menu stays where it is) which screams for "edit me".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

b is OK, you do not need multiple forms, just make it in different div like something here: http://jquery.redllama.net/jwizard/, and post that form at last

Comment: Good plugin (and answer)! The form would, however, load everything `onload` and just hide the rest `fieldsets`... would you recommend this for a form? The good thing here is that it would work without JS too. No AJAX right?

Comment: I don't think you need ajax as long as you do not need server side validation, but without js the wizard might not work.

Comment: I meant that the fields would still be accessible without JS. The plugin will definitely break.

Answer (score 0):

If I were in your place I would've definitely used **b**. If you go with a you will also have to write four form handlers on your server side.